# BASH: script doesn't recognize the files on the fly

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My script should do a simple trick - unpack the files as 'root' from tared file, and process them on the fly with different user. Smth like this.

```
 ./script   # starts with 'root' user
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#!/bin/bash
TAR="some.tar"
FILES=$(find /home/user \( -name "xxx*.yyy" \) | sort -n | tail -n 3)

tar -xpf $TAR --overwrite --same-owner -P 

sudo -u user bash <<- EOF   # switch to 'user'

        sh process_unpacked_$FILES.sh 

EOF
```

It works, however it doesn't catch the unpacked files (they appear in the directory) on the fly. I mean if i execute the same script again, when the files are already unpacked and exist in directory, script goes and finishes the trick.

The files in tar belong to 'user'. How to make the script work in a single execution?

Comment: Try adding sleep of about five seconds after tar command

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: @cyrus - I did some debugging, but didn't find anything, except the files are missing. But they are there. I think this is about processing with a different user, cannot find the reason.

Comment: @Sourav - after which one exactly?

Comment: So you run find to get the names of some files, and then you unpack a tarball and you expect that the files that were unpacked will travel back in time and be present when you ran find?  That seems like an unrealistic expectation.  If you want the newly unpacked files to be seen by find, you should run find after you unpack the tarball.

Comment: @William - i'm new to all this scripting stuff, so I was expecting the variable to be updated every time I call it, and bring the data even if it been updated... Isn't it working this way? :-/  Your explanation sounds logical and sheds many light on to my view of things. Will try this and update then. Thanks.

Comment: After this command" tar -xpf $TAR --overwrite --same-owner -P "  next line add
sleep 5

Comment: @SouravGulati - as i said the files have been unpacked. So sleep will no add anything

Comment: @WilliamPursell - thanks, it sorted the issue out.

Comment: If you want that type of functionality (that is, for the process to be run whenever you reference the variable), you can get it (but not with a simple variable reference.)  by doing `FILES() { find ... | tail -n3; }; sh process_unpacked_"$(FILES)".sh`